# Undefined Class when Logout Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm getting

> Class 'common\models\ErrorHandler' not found

When I logout both frontend & backend actions, and there's nothing different than normal logout

```
 /**
     * Logs out the user.
     * @return \yii\web\Response
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();
        return $this->goHome();
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: show your `errorHandler` config section

Comment: 'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],

Comment: defined in common/config , and it's only like the above

Comment: Put it in `frontend/config` and `backend/config`

Comment: I think it's something with your namespaces. You forget to add full namespace to ErrorHandler or something like this. Search `ErrorHandler` string in your project and specify it as `\yii\web\ErrorHandler`

Comment: @gmc common config is included both back and front (look at entry script)

Comment: @SiZE , yea I tried to add the namespace to all the 'common/models' but it didn't work , i updated my composer several times as well

Comment: @XXLend why you try to add namespace to all the 'common/models' to the class that does not belongs to that namespace?

Comment: @SiZE from what i get from the error some where in "common/models" the Error Handler is not defined .. which is not the case. !! what might be the reason ??

Comment: The problem exactly is that you define ErrorHadler: 1) without specify namespace inside on of the models under `common/models` OR 2) specify wrong namespace `common/models`. Please search class which use ErrorHandler and fix it's namespace. Thats all.